# Cannon open file by intent received by FileProvider

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-fileprovider, android-storage

I uploaded file from server, figured out it's mime type, received link by FileProvider, but when I select one of the applications to open document, it says that document is not excisting or impossible to open. However, when I open it from download folder manualy, all is fine.

My code for show off function

```
private fun openDownloadedDocument(
        context: Context,
        documentUri: Uri,
        docMimeType: String
    ) {
        var docUri: Uri? = documentUri

        if (docUri != null) {
            if (ContentResolver.SCHEME_FILE == docUri.scheme) {
                val file = File(docUri.path)
                docUri =
                    FileProvider.getUriForFile(requireActivity(), "${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.provider", file)
              }

            val openDocumentIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            openDocumentIntent.setDataAndType(docUri, docMimeType)
            openDocumentIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            try {
                context.startActivity(openDocumentIntent)
            } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
                Toast.makeText(
                    context,
                    context.getString(R.string.noSuitableActivity),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                ).show()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you doing any of this? You already have a Uri which you can pass to your `ACTION_VIEW` Intent directly.

Comment: FileProvider cannot be used for uploaded files.

Comment: ianhanniballake, because if I push directly argument string, I'll receive an exception:
 Caused by: android.os.FileUriExposedException:

Comment: blackapps, is there any way to open such file then? Mind to give a hint?

Comment: Use the url directly.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem, did you find a solution @SmirnovDV ?